# ReturningUserIntroCard in Virtual Assistant Template

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

In the Virtual Assistant Template introduction
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-virtual-assistant-template?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)
it is said that "a returning user card is shown on subsequent interactions".

I'm not able to have the returning ActiveCard shown.

What the user is supposed to do/say in the dialog to see that card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What the user is supposed to do/say in the dialog to see that card?

Start a new converstation after having previous interacted with the bot. For example, using the out-of-the-box VA, if you use the 'test in webchat' blade on Azure, you'll get a welcome card, and a prompt to enter your name. Later converstations, if you 'restart conversation' in that pane, you won't be prompted to enter your name, you'll get just the card.

In other channels, it would be as simple as sending 'hi' or 'are you there' to a bot to restart the convo after the bot has timed out (ie, the user hasn't messaged the bot after some time). This is known as a 'welcome card'.

For generic bot welcome messages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-send-welcome-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

For VA specific welcome messages:https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/virtual-assistant/tutorials/customize-assistant/csharp/2-edit-your-greeting/